# python beautifulsoup capture image

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

using below script i am trying to capture the image and then save it on disk. And then have to save the local path in the DB.

I have writting a simple code to capture the image from webpage:-

```
import urllib2
from os.path import basename
from urlparse import urlsplit
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.someweblink.com/path_to_the_target_webpage"
urlContent = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(''.join(urlContent))
imgTags = soup.findAll('img')
for imgTag in imgTags:
    imgUrl = imgTag['src']
    try:
        imgData = urllib2.urlopen(imgUrl).read()
        fileName = basename(urlsplit(imgUrl)[2])
        output = open(fileName,'wb')
        output.write(imgData)
        output.close()
    except:
        pass
```

The page code for image :-

```
<div class="single-post-thumb"> <img width="620" height="330" src="http://ccccc.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/weerewr.jpg"/>
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: the code i wrote is not able to capture the img link (the html code is also posted below). request if you can help in fixing the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to download the image using the url of the image you can try this

```
import urllib
img_url = "Image url goes here"
urllib.urlretrieve(img_url,'test.jpg')
```

It will save your image with test.jpg name in the current working directory.

Note: mention full url of the image sometimes "src" attribute of the img tag contains relative urls.